# How to pass popupparent property to a DLL

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

I pass the popupparent property from a program to a DLL.

When call two times to DLL the program raises an access violation.

This is my dll code:

```
library mydll;

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  System.Classes,
  Vcl.Forms,
  umydllform in 'umydllform.pas' {FormDLL};

{$R *.res}

procedure myfunction(Parent: TCustomForm); stdcall;
var
  A: TFormDLL;
begin
  A := TFormDLL.Create(nil);
  A.PopupMode := TPopupMode.pmAuto;
  A.PopupParent := Parent;
  A.ShowModal;
  A.PopupParent := nil;
  A.Free;
end;

exports
  myfunction;

begin

end.
```

This is the main form:

```
unit umainform;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm37 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  end;

var
  Form37: TForm37;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm37.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
type
  Tmyfunction = procedure(AOwner: TCustomForm); stdcall;
var
  H: HMODULE;
  F: Tmyfunction;
begin
  H := LoadLibrary(PChar('mydll.dll'));
  @F := GetProcAddress(H, 'myfunction');
  F(Application.MainForm);
  FreeLibrary(H);
end;

end.
```

The program runs the first time ok.
But the second time the dll is executed an exception ocurrs.
I need to assign the popup parent property so the form doesn't get left behind.

When FreeLibrary is not used the program runs ok two or more times.

Best regards,

Comment: It is not safe to pass objects over the DLL boundary like this. A safer option would be to pass the parent's HWND instead, and then have `TFormDLL` override its virtual `CreateParams()` method to assign that HWND to the `TCreateParams.WndParent` field. That is what the `PopupParent` would do internally anyway

Comment: You should be using run time packages if you want to share components between exe and dll.

Comment: http://www.rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-dlls.html